# Do Google doc's presentations pass accessibility standards?

Tags: google-slides, accessibility

Haven't been able to find much information online. There is a page for docs accessibility standards but I don't see specific points mentioned.

Do google doc's presentations meet accessibility standards? It seems like they say they do, but when I access the actual presentation, I can't click or highlight any text, and the markup seems a mess, though text is in the markup. Can a screen reader pick them up?

Basically I am just looking for an accessible way to present powerpoint-esque presentations online, and if google doc's presentations are accessible, then it's fine. But at least, when viewing the actual presentation (starting the presentation), the markup doesn't appear accessible so I am not 100% sure.

I see there is also a show presentation in HTML view, which is way more accessible but unfortunately doesn't have a slide manager/table of contents on it, which is kind of a shame.

Does anyone know or have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

I only have experience with text documents from Google Docs, but their accessibility appears abismal, and I must assume the same holds true for presentations. The only way I've been able to get a screen reader to read such a document is with the ctrl + alt + z keystroke (there is supposedly more information on shortcut keys available with ctrl + alt + /, but this does nothing for me). If the document takes too long to read, though, my screensaver comes up, and I can't just start reading from where I left off.

Whenever there's something on Google Docs that I want to read, I save the page and read it as source code. This is a cluttered mess, but it works better than trying to read it on the internet. I have no idea how this would apply to presentations.

If I am mistaken, I would love to be corrected; there are things I wouldn't mind reading that I just haven't felt were worth downloading and navigating as source code.

Answer (score 0):

Google has public accessibility statement for Google Slides, if you want to know which criteria they support and which not: https://www.google.com/slides/about/accessibility/

Also they provide tips for creating accessible presentations using Slides: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6199477

If you want to *edit* presentation using screen reader: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1634140

How to collaborate and comment with screen reader: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6239410

You can also try to present your Google Slides with auto created captions: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9109474

> When you present slides, you can turn on automatic captions to display the speaker's words in real time.